# Pyspark DecimalType formating for string

Tags: python, string, apache-spark, pyspark, format

I have a DataFrame which contains a column called `amount` and of type `DecimalType(38, 18)`. I want to add a new string column using the `formart_string()` function with a string like `"Amount is %f USD"` with different format (`%f`, `%.18f`, `%g`, `%d`) but I always get a Java exception saying the format is wrong :

```
py4j.protocol.Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling o1448.collectToPython.
: org.apache.spark.SparkException: Job aborted due to stage failure: Task 0 in stage 61.0 failed 1 times, most recent failure: Lost task 0.0 in stage 61.0 (TID 71) (e60e107be193 executor driver): java.util.IllegalFormatConversionException: f != org.apache.spark.sql.types.Decimal
```

What formatting am I supposed to use ? If possible I would like the value to be rounded to 2 decimals but using `%.02f` doesn't work either.

Comment: I also tried to cast the column as a `StringType()` and then format it in the string with `%s` but I got a similar error : `java.util.IllegalFormatConversionException: o != org.apache.spark.unsafe.types.UTF8String`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this :

```py
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
from pyspark.sql.functions import round, concat, lit, col

spark = SparkSession.builder.appName("format_decimal").getOrCreate()

data = [(1.234567891234567891,), (123456789.123456789123456789,), (0.000123456789123456789,)]
df = spark.createDataFrame(data, ["amount"])

df = df.withColumn("formatted_amount", round(col("amount"), 2).cast("string"))

formatted_column = concat(lit("Amount is "), col("formatted_amount"), lit(" USD"))
df = df.withColumn("formatted_string", formatted_column)

df.show(truncate=False)
```

Comment: Okay thanks. I was expecting Spark to do the conversion itself since we can use Java's string formats with floats, integers etc.

Answer (score 0):

If i understand your question correctly, you are trying to concat an Numerical type and an String type, so in Pyspark there are multiple options to achive that. we can create a new column `converted_col` by using the function withColumn as stated by Aymen,other options like `select`, `selectExpr` can also be used for the same. If you are familiar with SQL then it becomes more easy.

```
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
spark = (
    SparkSession
    .builder
    .appName("StackOverFlow")
    .getOrCreate()
)

data = [(1234.12343, ), (12345.12345, ), (123456.123456, )]
cols = ['amount']

df = spark.createDataFrame(data, cols)

# using selectExpr
df.selectExpr("*", "round(amount, 2) || ' USD' converted_col").show()

# SQL
df.createOrReplaceTempView("df")
select *, round(amount, 2) || ' USD' amount_str from df
```

so here i have used selectExpr, where it has the scope so that you can use SQL like statements directly without any spark API like using the concat, lit functions.

the return type of df.withColumn() , df.selectExpr(), df.select() is DataFrame type. So without any issues we can chain number of functions to the dataframe.

you can refer below reference for more explanation
https://spark.apache.org/docs/3.1.3/api/python/reference/api/pyspark.sql.DataFrame.selectExpr.html

selectExpr usuage:
https://sparkbyexamples.com/pyspark/pyspark-selectexpr/

difference between select & selectExpr
https://sparkbyexamples.com/spark/spark-select-vs-selectexpr-with-examples/

my take would be, if you are more comfortable with SQL, then working with pyspark dataframes will be easy.

Comment: Thanks, I was hoping Pyspark to handle the conversion inside the format_string function since we can pass decimal, floats and timestamps data using Java's formatting (%d etc.)

Comment: have you tried this, df.withColumn("converted_col", format_string("Amount is %.2f %s", col("amount"), lit("USD"))).show(10,0)

Comment: Yes and it fails on the %.2f saying decimaltype cannot be mapped to f

Comment: thats wierd when i have tried it worked for me, i tried the above solution in Databricks community edition (pyspark version is 3.x)